# How to have app resume instead of restart in iOS 13+

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am working on a SpriteKit game and whenever I press the home button and then come back to the app, my expected behavior would be that the game is paused, but the actual behavior is that the app is restarted and the main menu loads.

For the game, in order for a game to pause the app on receiving a phone call/leaving the app and coming right back, I have the following code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

Inside of `appMovedToBackground` the pausing logic is carried out. This works perfectly for devices on or below iOS 12. Testing on a device running iOS 13 however, and it is not working as expected. It does pause the game when opening Notification Center or Control Center, or just opening the multitasking pane (double clicking the home button) but when closing the app (just pressing the home button) or switching apps, and then coming back, the app restarts to the main menu.

I do not believe the pausing logic is relevant, since when I removed all of that logic, the app still resets. I would like to be able to close the app, reopen it and resume in the game scene.

The following message is being logged in the console when the app is closed:

```
SKView: ignoreRenderSyncInLayoutSubviews is NO. Call _renderSynchronouslyForTime without handler
```

I have looked this up and everything leads back to [this source](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649381) which says that this can be ignored, however, if I close the app and open the app before this message is logged, then the expected behavior is observed, so I do believe this may be related.